# PrePros license MIT but shareware at the same time?

Tags: licensing

[PrePros](https://github.com/Subash/Prepros) a compiler for the LESS/CSS languages is licensed under MIT

But from [version 5.0](https://prepros.io/) it being presented as 'Shareware' which requires payment and activation, although it does not impose any limits but prompts you to pay and Activate

I really don't understand what the deal is here. Am I required to pay for using it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened is that the owners of PrePros changed the license going from version 4 to version 5.

- Version 4 of PrePros is available under the MIT license and can be used, changed and redistributed freely.
- Version 5 of PrePros does not have an explicit copyright license, so you must assume that you are not allowed to make changes or redistribute it. Given the free download option, it can be assumed that you are allowed to use it for free, but with the restriction of the nagging. To get rid of the nagging (and possibly other features or rights) you need to pay.